# How to get the event target inside the parent component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a **Main component** with code

```
changeColor = (color) => {

}

toggle = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target)
}

<div>
  <EditComponent changeColor={this.changeColor.bind(this)}>
  <TextComonent toggle={this.toggle.bind(this)}>
</div>
```

**Edit component** is

```
color = (value) => {
  this.props.changeColor(value)
}
<div>
  <button value='red' onClick={this.color.bind(this,"red")}>Red</button>
  <button value='blue' onClick={this.color.bind(this,"blue")}>Blue</button>
</div>
```

**Text component** is

```
toggle = (e) => {
  this.props.toggle(e)
}
<div>
  <p class="black-color" onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>Text 1</p>
  <p class="black-color" onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>Text 2</p>
</div>
```

I will be clicking on `Text 1` or `Text 2` first and I will get the `event` inside `toggle` function. Next I will click the button `Red` or `Blue`. Then I want to change the class to either `red-color` or `blue-color` for that particular `Text` that i have clicked before. How can I get the event inside the parent component to find the particular `text` or is there any other way to to this?

I want to get the `event.target` inside the Parent component. I got the `event` object in parent but `event.target` is `null`

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you. The code currently in your question is not correct syntax.

Comment: I found the exact solution as to add `event.persist();` to get the `event.target` inside parent component.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
 <EditComponent changeColor={this.changeColor.bind(this)}>
 <TextComonent toggle={this.toggle}>
 </div>
```

try this way dont bind function in parent component and try,you will get the target

Comment: No. This doesn't give the target. Still it gives `null`

Comment: i tried your code in repl online editor its giving me target perfect

Comment: Please correct the link. 'go' is attached at the end

Comment: sorry for the mistake,try this https://repl.it/repls/EmbarrassedTallKeygen

Answer (score 0):

You are not using "bind" correctly. You don't need to bind with an anonymous function.

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <p onClick={(e) => this.toggle(e)}>
        Test
      </p>
    </div>);
  }

  toggle = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
    }
}
```

From the event variable in toggle, you can perform your changes as need be.

Comment: Yes I'm getting the event inside the toggle function of same component But I want to get it inside the parent component. That is where I'm struggling. There I got the `event` object but `event.target` is null

Comment: It should not be null with the correct way shown in my answer. Try the above and let me know.

Comment: No. You are getting inside the same Hello component. Can you pass the `event` as parameter to the props which calls the function inside the parent component and try getting it there inside the parent component as I did in my question?

Comment: You are passing the parent method to the child which is passed the event from the child.

Answer (score 0):

I found the exact solution as to add `event.persist();` to get the `event.target` inside parent component.